# Sort Nested document in MongooseJS

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my schema:

```
var Review = new Schema({
    user: {type: ObjectId, ref:'User'},
    lastModified: {type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var Subject = new Schema({
    name: String,
    review: [Review],
    ...
});


The query will return all the subjects with review from a user.
```

`{'review.user': id}`
    Is it possible to sort the result based on `review.lastModified`?

```
Subject.find({'review.user': id}).select('name').sort('???').exec( function(err, subjects){
    if (err) return res.json(error);

    console.log('subject', subjects);
});
```

Comment: Suppose the docs are Subject1[[review1(10), review(2)]], Subject1[[review1(3), review(4)]], I will just use a number as the date for simplicity, so what will be your expected result? I don't think it makes sense since Subject contains multiple dates and you can only sort them based on one date.

Comment: I mean on the date in the review

Comment: `review: [Review]` means an embedded array of `Review` docs, so as @sza says, this doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot sort within a document using MongoDB. Sorting within the document must be done at the application level.